# What does いられるかっ mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, potential-form, parsing

> 水着で密着されて無反応で**いられるかっ**

I roughly translated to

"Having the swimsuit stuck so close, there's no way you don't have a reaction"

What does いられるかっ mean in this sentence? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine the speaker is a man. He's saying "I can't stay clam/cool if she (who is in swimsuit) gets so close to me."

無反応でいられるかっ means "how can I stay cool?"

Answer (score 2):

[いられる](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%84%E3%82%89%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B) is the potential form of いる (to be/to exist) and か is the question marker.

So the _____ + いられるか portion means, "how can I be ______".

Comment: いられる(か) can be parsed as passive or potential. Considering the context it's more likely to be potential, which you translated correctly as "how can I (possibly) be _____"